# Can Gmail third party app access my phone number?

Tags: gmail, google-account

When an app (like signup using Google in website) access my Gmail contacts permission or other permissions, can that app know the phone number that registered with Gmail also used to recover the account?

Comment: no, unless its malicious app or its an app that is made to do exactly that (in this case you will be notified via permissions)

Answer (score -1):

The app uses Google APIs and this data is not exposed via the APIs any app has access to. So even a malicious app would not be able to obtain this data.